# if игнорируется компилятором

Tags: c++, if

```
    #include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

    string userOption;

void getUserOp()
{
    cout << "Хотите ли вы очистить консоль?\n да, нет" << endl;
    cin >> userOption; //Ввод строки от пользователя
    if (userOption == "Да") //Почему то игнорируется компилятором
    {
        system("cls"); //Очистка консоли
        cout << "Консоль очищена" << endl;
        cin.get();
    }
    else //Всегда выполняется, даже если пользователь ввёл "Да"
    {
        cout << "Консоль не очищена" << endl;
        cin.get();
    }
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    getUserOp(); //Вызов функци

    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Просите `yes\no` и не мучайтесь :)

Comment: Видимо, что-то с кодировкой...